Shell script unable to execute using full path
I have a simple korn shell script which will send sms to me whenever my database hits some error. I have a scheduler jobs which execute a store_proc to check the alert logs then trigger this shell script whenever there's any critical error occured.
Here's how's the scripts are written.
> #!/bin/ksh
> 
> export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1 export
> ORACLE_SID=$1 export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
> SMS_SENT=/tmp/ods_sms.txt echo `date` >> $SMS_SENT
> 
> 
> /bin/mail -s "ALERT :$1 ${2}" +phone_number < /dev/null

Script was given execute permission
ls -ltr send_sms.ksh
-rwxr-x--- 1 oracle oinstall 261 Nov  5 15:53 send_sms.ksh

If I were to execute this script directly in the folder it works. However in my store prod, I'm calling this script from it's full path & it's giving me No such file or directory error.
./home/oracle/monitor/send_sms.ksh
-bash: ./home/oracle/monitor/send_sms.ksh: No such file or directory

What am I missing here?

Remove leading . from your path so it reads /home/..... 

a bit of code review: echo `date`  is a useless echo: date already sends its output to stdout. You don't need to capture the output just to echo it on stdout.

Also, SMS_SENT=/tmp/ods_sms.txt echo ...anything... >> $SMS_SENT probably isn't going to do what you want. It's like saying x=foo echo $x and expecting it to echo foo, but it won't unless it was set beforehand. The $x is evaluated by the interpreter process, probably found empty, and passed as the (probably empty) argument to the command, which THEN sets x to foo for the process executing the echo, which isn't the process that parsed the command line already. That's why x=foo; echo $x does work; it sets the value in the interpreter, then passes that to the echo.
